# Inserting image path, into database

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been making a website, for a uni project, my code was pointed out as vulnerable, to SQL injections as I didn't use prepared statements. I'm in the process of rectifying that and I've ran into a wall, with the image upload. When I was just using standard MYSQLi queries, I understood the way it was assigned to the variable, now as I'm using placeholders and bound parameters, I'm a bit lost. Initially I couldn't get the image into the directory, although I've solved this now, by reading the forums. Now my image path is not storing in the database, i've tried numerous things to get it working and read around the forums, extensively. I just cannot get an example of an image upload, in MYSQLi, using a Prepare Statement. Hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction, so I understand better.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_product'])) {

    $destination = "C:/Ampps/www/Adaptive_Dev/images/".$_FILES['image']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);

    print_r($_FILES);

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO products
                                (productBrand,
                                productModel,
                                productModelNo,
                                productPrice,
                                productDesc,
                                productSpec,
                                productInTheBox,
                                productGuarantee,
                                productImage)
                                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssdsssis",
        $_POST['productBrand'],
        $_POST['productModel'],
        $_POST['productModelNo'],
        $_POST['productPrice'],
        $_POST['productDesc'],
        $_POST['productSpec'],
        $_POST['productInTheBox'],
        $_POST['productGuarantee'],
        $_FILES['ProductImage'] );
    $stmt->execute();
```

I've temporarily set the column to accept nulls, so the data passes to the database. I attempted to place a variable in the images' placeholder position, which threw all kind of errors. I just can't work out how to pass it, to the bound parameters.

```
Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => b&oM5Banner.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\Ampps\tmp\phpB39.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 269481 ) )
```

I've placed my print_r result here, I don't really know what other info I can give, I'm obviously doing something wrong and I can't work out what. Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Why `Ive temporarily set the column to accept nulls,`

Comment: `$_FILES['ProductImage']` does not exist

Comment: Try using `$destination` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is fairly obvious and has nothing to do with prepared statements.

You say this

> I've temporarily set the column to accept nulls,

Why would you do that, as it tells you what is wrong.  The path you are supplying is null.  It's generally a good Idea to listen to the warnings and errors you get, because they will tell you where to look.

Also you should have gotten a warning for using an undefined index, well if you had error reporting turned on, that is.  You can turn it on like this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

But back to the issue at hand, lets look at what you put in for the image path:

```
   $_FILES['ProductImage']
```

In the best case this is an array, not a path ( string ).  The `$_FILES` array is a super global in PHP, it has a special purpose.  That is, that this array contains the information about a file that is uploaded over HTTP.  You should know this because you used it to move the file from the "temp" folder to a permanent home.

So given all that the solution really is quite simple. Just use`$destination` variable which is the path where you put the file.  You can see that used in your code here:

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
```

Just to elaborate, an example of the contents of your `$_FILES` super global array looks something like this:

```
 $_FILES = [
      'image' => [
            'name' => 'b&oM5Banner.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'tmp_name' => 'C:\Ampps\tmp\phpB39.tmp',
            'error' => 0, 
            'size' => 269481
       ],
 ];
  //I know this because you output it with print_r
```

So when you try to use `$_FILES['ProductImage']` is it any wonder it doesn't work?

Hope that helps explain what happened and how to trouble shoot it.

Cheers.

Comment: It makes perfect sense now you've pointed it out. I set the image column to accept nulls as I wanted to make sure the rest of the data passed ok. As I'd been using standard queries, I didn't fully understand where to use the variable. That was about the only place I didn't put it. I mistakenly thought the FILES productImage was necessary, so I never omitted it. Thanks for pointing it out, I appreciate it.

Comment: Right, but doing that can make it harder to debug it.  That's all I was trying to say.  It's hard to convey context in text, hope it didn't sound to "harsh".  Good Luck and happy coding.

Comment: No, of course not. You took the trouble to answer and help me with my problem and along with the other guy, gave me some good guidance which I will definitely use. I didn't think it sounded harsh, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['ProductImage']` does not appear to exist, but you did create a variable called `$destination` with the path, so I assume you shoudl be using that.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_product'])) {

    $destination = "C:/Ampps/www/Adaptive_Dev/images/".$_FILES['image']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);

    print_r($_FILES);

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO products
                                (productBrand,
                                productModel,
                                productModelNo,
                                productPrice,
                                productDesc,
                                productSpec,
                                productInTheBox,
                                productGuarantee,
                                productImage)
                                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssdsssis",
        $_POST['productBrand'],
        $_POST['productModel'],
        $_POST['productModelNo'],
        $_POST['productPrice'],
        $_POST['productDesc'],
        $_POST['productSpec'],
        $_POST['productInTheBox'],
        $_POST['productGuarantee'],
        //$_FILES['ProductImage'] );
        $destination );
    $stmt->execute();
```

> In future while testing add these lines to the top of your script and errors will appear on the browser, even if you are developing with Error dispays turned off, like a hosting site.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Oh yea, and me too, if you look at my comment

Comment: I don't downvote answers, ever.  So it wasn't me. I can up vote it if you want.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Ok, cool, must of been a passing syntax checker that noticed I forgot a semi colon after `$destination )`  :)

Comment: @ezw Actually my answer was 1 minute after the other own, But my comment to the same effect was 1 minute before the other answer. But what was your point?

Comment: Thank you, for replying and pointing out my mistake. I appreciate it, so thanks